# Comparing exponents.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there an easy way to compare $a^m$ and $b^n$ where $1 \le a, b, m, n \le 1000$ without raising the corresponding bases to their power (since it can easily cause an overflow)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the logs to your favorite base and compare $m \log a$ and $n \log b$.  This looks like it bears on [Euler project 29.](http://projecteuler.net/problem=29)